# Google Maps is not coming when I transit the page from main page by link

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to mobile application development, and I am integrating Google Maps in my app by jQuery mobile. When I change pages by giving a reference to an html page, it is not showing the map. In fact, it is not getting in to the function of that file.

**map.html:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100%;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBUuNWrZ1zjJ7yKV3DJL2ylrhj9BAcYo8A&sensor=true&language=ka">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function initialize() {
         alert("map");
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.38504, 78.48667),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      }
   </script>

  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" data-fullscreen="true">
        <div data-role="header" >
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <a href="src/contact.html" ><img src="iphone-contacts-icon.jpg" width="72" height="72"  hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
                <a href="src/map.html"><img src="Maps-icon.png" width="72" height="72" hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
                <a><img src="ExamIcon.jpg" width="72" height="72" hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->

</div><!-- Content-->
        <div data-role="footer" >
            <h1>footer</h1>
        </div>  <!-- footer-->
    </div>  <!-- page-->


</body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your pages working by rearranging some of the javascript. This is what the two html pages look like now:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBUuNWrZ1zjJ7yKV3DJL2ylrhj9BAcYo8A&sensor=true&language=ka">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $('#Map').live("pageinit", function (event) {
         alert("map");
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.38504, 78.48667),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body >
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" data-fullscreen="true">
        <div data-role="header" >
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <a href="src/contact.html" ><img src="iphone-contacts-icon.jpg" width="72" height="72"  hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
                <a href="map.html"><img src="Maps-icon.png" width="72" height="72" hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
                <a><img src="ExamIcon.jpg" width="72" height="72" hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->

</div><!-- Content-->
        <div data-role="footer" >
            <h1>footer</h1>
        </div>  <!-- footer-->
    </div>  <!-- page-->


</body>
</html>
```

**map.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">

    <div data-role="page" id="Map">
        <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
      body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
      #Map { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    </style>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason why your javascript wasn't loading before is because jQuery Mobile doesn't load the entire document of subsequent pages. It only loads the specified div containing the attribute data-role="page" or if such a div doesn't exist, it loads the body of the document.
The reason why it doesn't load the head of the document is because it tries to avoid loading the same scripts multiple timese.

Hope this helps you out.

EDIT:

in this case you could also embed the map page into your index.html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBUuNWrZ1zjJ7yKV3DJL2ylrhj9BAcYo8A&sensor=true&language=ka">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $('#Map').live("pageinit", function (event) {
         alert("map");
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.38504, 78.48667),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body >
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" data-fullscreen="true">
        <div data-role="header" >
            <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <a href="src/contact.html" ><img src="iphone-contacts-icon.jpg" width="72" height="72"  hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
                <a href="#Map"><img src="Maps-icon.png" width="72" height="72" hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
                <a><img src="ExamIcon.jpg" width="72" height="72" hspace="10" vspace="20"/></a>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->

</div><!-- Content-->
        <div data-role="footer" >
            <h1>footer</h1>
        </div>  <!-- footer-->
    </div>  <!-- page-->

    <div data-role="page" id="Map">
        <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
      body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
      #Map { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    </style>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Falle,
thanks for your response...
It is working in a same file but in dreamweaver but not in Phone gap.
and with two files it is still not working. Is there any lib or any config needed??

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that JQM uses ajax to load that second page. When JQM gets your second page for the map it is looking for a JQM formatted page(**note** this is different for JQM 1.1).

i.e.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So your google maps library isn't getting loaded. To solve this move your google maps library to that first page. Then you need to write your google maps code to start on the pageshow event. This is important because if you do it before the pageshow your map will be offcenter. Here is how to bind to pageshow.

```
$(document).delegate('#mapPage', 'pageshow', function(){
    var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.38504, 78.48667),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
});
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: Hi codaniel....
thanks for reply n give suggetion. but still i m not getting the  map by bind map initialize function according to u.

in my above qus is when i load the map file, that time initialize() function is not calling. It just execute body part of map.html.

Comment: Instead of using the initialize function and body onload bind to the pageshow event like I show above.